# File inconsistency... doesn't appear in 'ls -a' but it exists?

Tags: backup, filesystems, rsync, fat32, file-corruption

I’ve run `rsync` (3.0.6) on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard )to backup a folder form an external hard drive (FAT32) to another external hard disk (FAT32). Somehow certain files (and at times they change!) get copied with a different file name. For example:

```
campo_2006_valcanale_127.jpg --> CAMPO~40.JPG
```

Shrunk and upper-cased, of course rsync next time deletes the CAMPO~40.JPG and copies it again, but almost always it gets messed up again. At times it works, but also files that were OK get corrupted.

Now, if I go in the destination directory and do a `ls -a` I can’t see the file `campo_2006_valcanale_127.jpg` because it has been somehow renamed but the file `campo_2006_valcanale_127.jpg` actually exists! I can display it, I can write on it etc…, simply it’s invisible! Maybe it’s just the filename that's behaving oddly…

I get the same behavior when I copy files manually (using `cp`) and even when I copy them with the “Finder!” I drag and drop a file and its name changes!

If you have *any* hint, please tell me… I can provide more info if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortened filenames are artifact of FAT32; any file with a name longer than the old 8.3 limits gets given a shortened name, as you've seen. Use a proper filesystem, one that handles long filenames natively instead of using a bizarre hack, and you won't have this problem (eg, NTFS, HFS, ext - all handle long filenames natively). Wikipedia has more detail on the [Long Filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_filename) hack that FAT32 uses

FAT32 also has other issues that make it hard for rsync to work - eg, it doesn't store timestamps with any great precision, so rsync can't use its normal heuristics.

The rsync FAQ has an [entry](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/FAQ.html#2) on rsync copying the same files many times. In short, it's probably the timestamp that's causing most of the re-syncing; `modify-window=1` or maybe `modify-window=2` should fix this.

Comment: yes I know this, but the odd thing is that at times it happens, while at other times it doesn't..

My problem is that I'm in a mac/windows environment.. and this hdd must be accessed by both macs an computers..

Comment: Which sucks, because there's no good filesystem that all Mac, Windows and Linux can all access easily except fat32, so we're all stuck with this mess *sigh*

Comment: OSX & Linux can use NTFS-3g to read/write NTFS, so there's *no more need for FAT32* -- toss it!!

Comment: Not out-of-the-box; although most distros of linux should include FUSE and ntfs-3g by now.